# Create trigger with combining char

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have this working code. Every time I ran `INSERT INTO "HR"."CITY" (CITY_ID) VALUES (0);` the data in `CITY_ID` will increase by one like this `CT0001, CT0002 ... CT0015`.

```
 CREATE TABLE "HR"."CITY" 
   (    
    "CITY_ID" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
   ) ;


  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "HR"."PK_MAX_TRIGGER_CITY" 
BEFORE INSERT ON CITY
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    CNT NUMBER;
    PKV CITY.CITY_ID%TYPE;
    NO NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)INTO CNT FROM CITY;

    IF CNT=0 THEN
        PKV:='CT0001';
    ELSE
        SELECT 'CT'||LPAD(MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(CITY_ID,3,LENGTH(CITY_ID)))+1),4,'0') INTO PKV
        FROM CITY;
    END IF;
    :NEW.CITY_ID:=PKV;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "HR"."PK_MAX_TRIGGER_CITY" ENABLE;
```

What I want to do is this `E1, E2 ... E15`.

I change the code to:

```
    IF CNT=0 THEN
        PKV:='E1';
    ELSE
        SELECT 'E'||LPAD(MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(CITY_ID,3,LENGTH(CITY_ID)))+1),4,'0') INTO PKV
```

It work at first adding `E1` to database but not the second time. What inside the bracket is just to hard for me to digest. I was hoping anyone here could explain to me what actually happen in the bracket and helping me to solve this thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to modify your Else part query .

```
SELECT 'E'||(MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(CITY_ID,2))+1)) INTO PKV
    FROM CITY;
```

*Explaination*
Whenever you want to find what is happening in the brackets start with the inner bracket .

```
See the result of this query:  SELECT SUBSTR(CITY_ID,2) FROM CITY;
```

Here,you will extract the string after `E`,where `E` always there in 1st position ,so we will find the string from the `2nd position` . 
Then

```
 SELECT TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(CITY_ID,2)) FROM CITY ;
```

--this is converting the string into number.Then it will find the max number from the table CITY,and add 1 after that

```
SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(CITY_ID,2)))+1 FROM CITY ;
```

And finally appending the constant `E` with the result .

```
SELECT 'E'||(MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(CITY_ID,2))+1)) INTO PKV
    FROM CITY;
```

But take my suggestion ,create a sequence `city_id_seq`,this will be better solution than what you are doing now.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE city_id_seq
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 99999999999
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 20;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "HR"."PK_MAX_TRIGGER_CITY" 
BEFORE INSERT ON CITY
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
 v_city_id PLS_INTEGER;  
BEGIN
  SELECT city_id_seq.nextval INTO v_city_id  FROM DUAL;

 :NEW.CITY_ID :='E'||v_city_id  ;

/*  if you are using oracle 11g 
:NEW.CITY_ID:='E'||city_id_seq.nextval; 
*/

END;
/
```

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your explanation. If I understand correctly this `SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(CITY_ID,2)))+1 FROM CITY ;` Select max numbers and then increment by 1? and than this `'E'||` does it mean `E or` because the sign `||`?

Comment: I got error with your suggestion code. `Errors for TRIGGER HR.PK_MAX_TRIGGER_CITY:` The error is `PL/SQL: Statement ignored` and `PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'CITY_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL ' not allowed in this context`. Any idea?

Comment: @sg552:which version of oracle are you using ,this syntax works in Oracle 11g ,otherwise use select statement in the trigger to fetch sequence

Comment: @sg552:I have edited my Answer,and regarding your question to the first comment ,yes it is picking the max number part of the CITY_ID already existing in the table ,and `'E'` is just a Character ,because its under quotes ,if we dint specified within quotes then probably sign .

Comment: I appreciate your reply. I have read Oracle documentation regarding `dual` and this thing `||` but I still couldn't understand it. Please allowed me to asked you this question. `SELECT city_id_seqtest.nextval INTO v_city_id  FROM DUAL;` What is this `DUAL` exactly do in this command? I've read it and this are for dummy data? So why need it `FROM DUAL;`? Also this thing `||` What does this thing do exactly. I hope you can answer me. I use 10g. Appreciate your reply. Thank you.

Comment: @sg552:Lets take an example ,suppose you want to select all the records from the city table ,then what you will do .You'll do a select ,because you ware interested in city table records .Now if you are not interested in any data from table .And you want to do `substr('E123,2)`,then what you'll expect from the result `123` correct .But if you do `select substr('E123',2) from city `,it will give you as many as `123` as many records are present in city table,which you dnt want .So dual is just a dummy table,which contains only one record ,you want to select ,whcih will give you only one record .

Comment: @sg552:`||` is just a concatenation operator appending `E` with number

Answer (score 0):

The bracketed code ::

```
select LPAD(MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('CT0015',3,LENGTH('CT0015')))+1),4,'0') from dual;
```

is actually cutting the value of city_id from 3 position to the end of the string then converting it to number data type adding 1 and then padding zeros to the left side

so in this case o/p 0016